# Vinculando Usuários a Empresas e trazendo registros relacionados à empresa do Usuário usando ASP.NET Identity e Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Tenho registros no banco de dados (exemplo, clientes), e em todos os registros tem um identificador `EmpresaID`. Estou utilizando `identity` com **entity framework** para fazer a autenticação. No cadastro do usuário tenho um identificador "EmpresaId".

Gostaria de saber como faço pra trazer apenas os registros que o `EmpresaId` do cliente seja igual ao `EmpresaId` do usuário no código abaixo:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
    RegisterViewModel usuario = new RegisterViewModel();
    var exames = db.Exames.Include(p => p.Empresa);

    return View(db.Exames.ToList());
}
```

Atualmente traz todos os registros:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
    RegisterViewModel usuario = new RegisterViewModel();
    var exames = db.Exames.Include(p => p.Empresa);

    return View(db.Exames.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é que seu `Usuario` tenha a propriedade `EmpresaId` da seguinte forma:

```
public class Usuario : IdentityUser
{
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
}
```

Assim, você recupera as informações do seu usuário da seguinte forma:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var meuUsuario = db.Set<Usuario>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
```

Juntando tudo:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //var empresa = new Empresa();
    //var usuario = new RegisterViewModel();
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var meuUsuario = db.Set<Usuario>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
    var exames = db.Exames.Include(p => p.Empresa).Where(e => e.EmpresaId == meuUsuario.EmpresaId);

    return View(exames.ToList());
}
```

Note que simplifiquei bastante seu código. Não é preciso instanciar `empresa` e `usuario` porque eles podem ser obtidos de outros lugares do *framework*.

Isto aqui:

```
var exames = db.Exames.Include(p => p.Empresa).Where(e => e.EmpresaId == meuUsuario.EmpresaId);
```

Não gera uma lista: gera um objeto do tipo `IQueryable<Exame>`, ou seja, um objeto de uma consulta que ainda não foi executada.

A consulta é executada apenas aqui, na chamada a `.ToList()`:

```
    return View(exames.ToList());
```